# How to change the color of the top menu bar on Monterrey to light gray?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, menu-bar, color

I just upgraded my mac from Big Sur to Monterey and the color of the top bar changed from gray to this color:
[image]

I went to system preferences->Accessibility->Display and checked "Reduce transparency" and that made it this color:
[image]

I want the light gray color that I had before. If I check "invert colors" it makes the top bar light gray but the rest of the display is too bright.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Are you interested in a tool that changes your wallpaper intelligently to accomplish this? https://github.com/igorkulman/ChangeMenuBarColor

Comment: In Monterey the menu bar is based on the colors of the wallpaper under it and you can't override that.  All you can do is put the color you want under it.  Either by hand, or with tools like `ChangeMenuBarColor`.

Comment: Basically, the menu bar has transparency so if your wallpaper is lighter towards the top, your menu bar will take its colour. I wanted to make it dark so I removed the transparency (I'm using dark mode).  **Accessibility** > **Display** and checked "Reduce transparency". The transparency of the tab switcher is also gone. But I'm fine with it, at least for now.

Comment: None of the solutions work for me. I have the Reduce Transparency accessibility setting enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Another tool is at:
https://manytricks.com/menubartint/

It's free.

Answer (score 6):

On Ventura you can just select a plain color wallpaper.
System Setting > Wallpaper from the left sidebar. Then select the plain black or other mono-color circle swatch (black shown in the screenshot).
Personally, I don't want the menu bar to stand out, but if you do, select a mono color that suits you. You can also create plain backgrounds using the + sign.[image: Mono Color Background]

Comment: Woah Apple, why the heck should I have to change the wallpaper to change the colour of the menu bar? I want my custom wallpaper AND a different colour menu bar!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Boring Old Menu Bar](https://www.publicspace.net/BoringOldMenuBar/).

It isn't free, but it works well and includes default style presets, unlike other tools which require you to rebuild the previous macOS styles manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use any photo editor to insert a gray space at the top of your menu bar. You can use Preview's Markup to add a gray block.

Comment: I think you mean wallpaper rather than menu bar. 